# Burn [get] and [post]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

When I say "get", what does it mean to you? A GET request? To retrieve something? To query a database? To call the `get` method on a C# property? [get](/questions/tagged/get) appears to encompass all of those and more. We should either burn it or split it up.

However, splitting it up would just result it [get-request](/questions/tagged/get-request). For the SQL query, we already have [sql](/questions/tagged/sql). Ultimately, most should questions should be retagged [get-request](/questions/tagged/get-request).

Its tag wiki suggests that it is for the HTTP GET protocol, however, there are quesions tagged with [get](/questions/tagged/get) that don't fit that description. A manual retag might be the only solution with ~375 questions tagged with it. There are also some that have both the [http](/questions/tagged/http)[get](/questions/tagged/get) tags. The fact that you need two to describe the question shows that they *really* should be changed to [get-request](/questions/tagged/get-request).

As suggested by RiaD, maybe use [http-get](/questions/tagged/http-get). We could maybe burn [post](/questions/tagged/post) and replace it with [http-post](/questions/tagged/http-post)?

Comment: I would name it [tag:http-get]

Comment: Questions are constantly being tagged with it. Look at sorted by recents. At this moment, there is one from an hour ago, one from 4 hours ago, 7 hours ago... I think we shouldn't just burn it, but ban it.

Comment: See also the poor, oft-abused [tag:set] tag ([this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17713543/revisions) was tagged both [tag:get] and [tag:set]).

Comment: @michaelb958 those poor little tags! They never did anything wrong and yet they're being abused by new users! It's unethical!

Comment: @ColeJohnson I was thinking about a Meta post dedicated to those two unfortunate tags, but this question covers some of it already.

Comment: Both _http\_post_ and _http-get_ should be made into _http-request_ instead.

Comment: reflagged? I *like* that word.

Comment: Generally, when there's lots of work to do, it's best left to people with edit privileges, to give the mods a break. It's fine to flag the mods for one or two things here and there, but if there's a whole series of 'em, don't.

Comment: Both [http-post] and [http-get] are existing tags, so we should definitely retag to those.

Comment: @hjpotter92, there are enough nuances to GET and POST in the context of various languages and platforms to support keeping their own tags, IMO... just barely.

Comment: @Charles can you elaborate?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, while the rules for parsing GET and POST are identical everywhere, how each platform handles accessing those values is different.  There's enough of a difference here that keeping them as separate but similarly named things is worth it, IMO.

Comment: @Charles feel free to make that an answer.